# Symmetric difference of 3 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In symmetric difference of three sets, is the Venn diagram for $(A \Delta B) \Delta C$  similar to $A \Delta B \Delta C$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: First off, if you don't expect them to be equal, then $A \Delta B \Delta C$ is automatically ambiguous. Did you mean $A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ instead?

Comment: @Arthur: Actually,if you don't expect them to be equal, then $A\triangle B\triangle C$ is actually undefined (because if it is not defined as either $(A\triangle B)\triangle C$ or $A\triangle (B\triangle C)$ then you'll have to explicitly define it as something different).